# can't post the following question in stack overflow, why?

Tags: support

I'm building a 3d (red,cyan) program. It went well, but when combining, the "image" (see in code) doesn't seemed to be affected. what is my mistake?

assume:
RImage_P(point)= {5,5}
startCyan (point) = {0,0}
startRed (point) = {5,5}
CImage, RImage are below the code.
image result is a fully black transparent image.
for testing and debugging, I have commented the Alpha ( the results are the same)

```
private void bitCombine(System.Drawing.Point startCyan, System.Drawing.Point startRed)
    {

       using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(CImage.Width + Math.Abs(RImage_P.X), CImage.Height + Math.Abs(RImage_P.Y),PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {

            var rectfull = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, CImage.Width, CImage.Height);
            var bitsC = CImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                        , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var bitsA = alpha.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                        , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var bitsOutput = image.LockBits(rectfull, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly
                                        , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            unsafe
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < CImage.Height; y++)
                {
                    byte* ptrC = (byte*)bitsC.Scan0 +  y * bitsC.Stride;
                    byte* ptrA = (byte*)bitsA.Scan0 +  y * bitsA.Stride;
                    byte* ptrOutput = (byte*)bitsOutput.Scan0 
                                      + (y+startCyan.Y)* bitsOutput.Stride;
                    for (int x = 0; x < CImage.Width; x++)// cyan values
                    {// gui+ is reversed BGRA
                        ptrOutput[4 * (x+startCyan.X)] = ptrC[4 * x];           // blue
                        ptrOutput[4 * (x + startCyan.X) + 1] = ptrC[4 * x + 1];// green
                      //ptrOutput[4 * (x + startCyan.X) + 3] = ptrA[4 * x + 3];// alpha


                    }
                }
                CImage.UnlockBits(bitsC);

                var bitsR = RImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
                                           , PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                for (int y = 0; y < RImage.Height; y++)// red values
                {
                    byte* ptrR = (byte*)bitsR.Scan0 + y  * bitsR.Stride;
                    byte* ptrA = (byte*)bitsA.Scan0 + y  * bitsA.Stride;
                    byte* ptrOutput = (byte*)bitsOutput.Scan0
                                       + (y+ startRed.Y) * bitsOutput.Stride;
                    for (int x = 0; x < RImage.Width; x++)
                    {// gui+ is reversed BGRA
                        ptrOutput[4 * (x + startRed.X) + 2] = ptrR[4 * x + 2];   // red
                       //ptrOutput[4 * (x + startRed.X) + 3] = ptrA[4 * x + 3];// alpha
                    }
                }

                RImage.UnlockBits(bitsR);
                alpha.UnlockBits(bitsA);
                image.UnlockBits(bitsOutput);


                this.image = image;

            }
        }
    }`
```

the images:(I guess I can't show them on this site...)
[CIamge](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg94/scaled.php?server=94&filename=66927197.png&res=landing)
[RImage](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg209/scaled.php?server=209&filename=19892665.png&res=landing)

Comment: Suspended, perhaps?

Comment: 1. I'm not suspended. 2. all of my code is in the box... ( start: private void... end:...this.image = image; }}})

Comment: Is this your first attempt at posting a question on Stack Overflow? Can you at least share the error message you get when trying to post this? One possibility is that the section after `assume:` *looks* like unformatted code.

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.... what do am I missing?

Comment: That might be due to the `RImage_P(point)= {5,5}` and such before your code block. That looks a lot like code. It might trick the system into thinking you didn't format properly. Try to format that as code for now and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Try formatting that section as a list, perhaps with `\`inline code blocks\``.

Comment: Bart is correct, thank you Bart.

Comment: So you were able to post that question now? (Just asking because I don't see it appear in your profile). Nevermind, I see you have multiple accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/users/656604/almog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post is confusing the algorithm that tries to detect that a user is posting code without properly formatting it.  Very high odds that the 5 lines that start with "assume" cause this.  Pretty odd that you got them all on a separate line like you did, that normally requires `<br>`.

Indent those lines by 4 spaces to un-confuse the algorithm.

Comment: OT, but instead of a `<br/>`, two spaces at the end will also do the trick.